# Check if request.user has a Valid Refresh Token?

Tags: django, rest, jwt, token

I have this Python3.7 Django 3.2.13 code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator

@api_view('POST')
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def sign_out(request):

    # Get the refresh_token from POST data...
    refresh_token = request.data.get("refresh")

    # We want to know if the refresh_token is associated with the current user?
    is_refresh_token_valid = default_token_generator.check_token(request.user, refresh_token)
```

Now, this always returns False. This check_token works when I use it on an access token instead. Is there way to get this to function with a refresh token instead?

Thanks!
Erik W.